# Android Studio - Updating requires uninstalling added certs

Tags: android, android-studio

Where I work I need to install new certificates to Android Studio's keystore in order to connect with our servers. On mac this is at `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. When I want to update, I always get the error below since I modified the cacerts file and so have to manually uninstall my certs, restart the update, and then reinstall after completion of the update. Is there any easy way to get around this other than manually uninstalling the certs? I understand the need to validate and prevent the possibility of malicious certs being present on installation but there has to be a better way.

[image: Image of error - Some conflicts where found in the installation area]